# CMake: possible to reuse custom command between targets in different CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a parent directory `root` with two subdirectories, `vairant_a` and `variant_b`. Both of the two variants compile the files `x.cxx`, `y.cxx`, and `z.cxx` from the parent directory. They also need to include a source file that `gen_script.pl` generates.

```
[root]
|\- [variant_a]
| |- CMakeLists.txt
| |- a.cxx
|
|\- [variant_b]
| |- CMakeLists.txt
| |- b.cxx
|
|- CMakeLists.txt
|- x.cxx
|- y.cxx
|- z.cxx
|- gen_source.txt
|- gen_script.pl
```

My parent `CMakeLists.txt` looks like this (assume `${ROOT}` is set to `root`):

```
set(SHARED_SOURCES
    ${ROOT}/x.cxx
    ${ROOT}/y.cxx
    ${ROOT}/z.cxx
)

add_subdirectory(variant_a)
add_subdirectory(variant_b)
```

And my subdirectory CMakeLists.txt look something like this:

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${GEN_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/gen_source.cxx
    COMMAND perl ${ROOT}/gen_script.pl ${ROOT}/gen_source.txt
)

add_custom_target(gen_source_a DEPENDS ${GEN_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/gen_source.cxx)

add_library(variant_a MODULE
    ${GEN_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/gen_source.cxx
    ${SHARED_SOURCES}
    a.cxx
)

add_dependencies(variant_a
    gen_source_a
)
```

The custom command that produces `gen_source.cxx` and the corresponding custom target are the same in `variant_a`'s and `variant_b`'s `CMakeLists.txt`.

I figured I could define just one custom command and custom target in `root`'s `CMakeLists.txt`, but just moving the code doesn't work - CMake complains that it can't find `${GEN_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/gen_source.cxx` when it's trying to process the `add_library` command in either of the subdirectories during the configure stage.

How could I properly reuse the custom command (or, even better, its output) between targets here?

Comment: Hmm, I don't think it's possible, if I'm interpreting this discussion correctly: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/18399

Comment: OK, the only workaround I've come up so far is to add a custom command in each of the subdirectories' CMakeLists.txt. The command depends on the parent's target and touches the generated file: https://www.codepile.net/pile/1EnBvREq

Comment: Is the generated `gen_source.cxx` the same for both variants?

Comment: Not related to the topic, but u can use the interface source library to "link" w/ both variants instead of `SHARED_SOURCES` variable. Also, no need to define a custom target unless u want explicitly run it separately from building other targets. It's enough to add the generated source to both modules.

Comment: Also, no need to use `GEN_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` I believe it's somewhere under `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` anyway... Less variables → clean code, easy to understand.

Comment: I have a few variables defined relative to `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR`, e.g. `set(GEN_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/gen)`. There are other reasons for this.

Comment: When you say, "Also, no need to define a custom target unless u want explicitly run it separately from building other targets", don't I need to define a custom target in the parent CMakeLists.txt to reference it in a subdirectory's? I realize that I don't need it as written, but I wanted to show the code that would be moved to the parent CMakeLists.txt. In my workaround version, I don't have the target in the subdirectories, just the command to touch the file

Comment: Use an object library.

Comment: @TatianaRacheva, You may have a source/object library on top and use it w/ `target_link_libraries` in subdirs. There is no need to have a custom target. It's enough to have a generated source (make sure it's marked as `GENERATED`) in the source/object library you linked w/ to trigger the generation.

Comment: Have you tried with CMake 3.20-rc1? According to the release notes,  "The GENERATED source-file property is now visible from any directory scope, regardless of the scope in which it is set. See policy CMP0118.". This should then prevent CMake from checking the existence of the generated source file at configuration time.

Comment: @Corristo no I have not! I'm using 3.19.1

Comment: @zaufi, I'll try this suggestion. I'm not marking the files as GENERATED currently - will do, too!